# Microsoft Azure Passing the user group or role to the specific user

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

I am trying to pass the user ROLE to the destination source from the Azure and I am not able to do.
[image]
I see this two provisions but only one gets fired(user) whenever I run the provision.
And to pass the roles from the Azure do I have to buy one of these?[image]

If yes, which one should I go with?
The user credentials are properly mapped but the Role part is missing. Need some help regarding with Role part. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

According to the [**MsDoc**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/plan-auto-user-provisioning#application-licensing), please note that:

> **If Azure AD manages automatic provisioning based on roles, the roles assigned in Azure AD must align to application licenses. Incorrect licenses owned in the application may lead to errors during the provisioning/updating of a user.**

*Provisioning Azure Ad users is supported in all licenses.*

Whereas provisioning Azure Ad group is only possible with  **Azure Active Directory Premium P1**/**Azure Active Directory Premium P2** licenses.

[image]

- Azure AD Premium P1 includes Microsoft 365 E3.
- Azure AD Premium P2, includes with Microsoft 365 E5.

**So, I suggest you to go with Azure AD Premium P2 license.**

**References:**

[Plan an automatic user provisioning deployment for Azure Active Directory - Microsoft Entra | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/app-provisioning/plan-auto-user-provisioning)

[Azure Active Directory Pricing | Microsoft Security](https://www.microsoft.com/en-in/security/business/identity-access-management/azure-ad-pricing?rtc=1)